# Spring JDBC Postgresql where in like

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-jdbc

I have following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM user_info
WHERE phone_number IN (:phoneNumbers)
```

I want to search not by exact phone number but using LIKE for each one. How I can implement that?

Comment: use `WHERE phone_number like 'pattern%' or phone_number like 'otherpatter%' ` and so on over `OR`

Comment: but I'm passing list here...

Comment: suggested some code in my answer. don't have spring to try

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `LIKE` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE phone_number LIKE '123%'
```

This query will match all phonenumbers starting with 123. If you need to match a phonenumber which contains 123, you should use:

```
SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE phone_number LIKE '%123%'
```

Now it'll match ANY phonenumber which contains 123. In PostgreSQL you don't need to cast a number to string if using LIKE (PostgreSQL does it for you automagically).

Comment: but I'm passing list here.

Comment: @asdasdsdf so you have to use `SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE phone_number LIKE ANY (array['123%', '%123%'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use PostgreSql [SIMILAR TO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) with regex.

Comment: how should I update my input if I'm passing list here - something like '111,222,333'?

Comment: `select * from user_info  where phone_number similar to '%(111|222|333)%';`

Comment: You can use also `ANY` syntax https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18025

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_info
WHERE phone_number like any ( array['123%', '456%'] );
```

Not sure how you pass an array from within Spring JDBC Template though

Answer (score 0):

you can do some monstrous workaround, like:

```
t=# with a as (values('some','postg','temp'))
, p as (select unnest(string_to_array(translate((a.*)::text,'()',''), ',')) patt from a)
select datname,concat(patt,'%') from p left outer join pg_database on datname like concat(patt,'%');
  datname  | concat
-----------+--------
           | some%
 postgres  | postg%
 template1 | temp%
 template0 | temp%
(4 rows)
```

here I use outer join to demonstrate how it works (`some%` does not match any dbname and thus datname is null). List `'some','postg','temp'` should be put to `values`, not to `IN` scalar list.
Also I know my dtabases do not have `()` in names , thus use `translate` here, instead of cutting first and last parenthesis.